# If $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, pointwise-convergence

If $f_n: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are integrable functions and $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then is it true that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x
$$

I know it holds if $f_n \to f$ uniformly, but not necessarily for pointwise convergence, but cannot think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<\frac1n\\\frac1x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ fonverges pointwise to$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x=0\\\frac1x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Each $f_n$ is Riemann-integrable, but $f$ isn't. Actually, the same thing occurs with the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: You might mention that the limit is not even Lebesgue integrable (hence the ambiguity regarding the word  "integrable" in the question does't matter, the answer is no regardless...)

Comment: Nice suggestion! I've edited my answer. Thank you.